# Why the ngFor in angular not printing the statements or data on browser that i am getting from my Spring Boot application

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

When working on SpringBoot and angular connectivity I was passing data like getbooks by getmapping through JSON and it is getting printed on the server of Spring but after passing these values to angular using service angular is not printing the data on the server.

#SpringBoot Controller File -

```
 @RestController
    public class BookController {
        
    @Autowired
    BookService bookservice;
        
            @GetMapping("/")
            public String homePage() {
                return "This is home Page";
            }
        
            @GetMapping("/addBook")
            public String addBook(int id, String name, String author) {
                bookservice.addBook(Book.builder().id(id).name(name).author(author).build());
                return "Book Added";
        
            }
        
            @GetMapping("/deleteBook")
            public String deleteBook(int id) {
                bookservice.deleteBook(id);
                return "Book deleted";
            }
        
            @GetMapping("/getBooks")
            public String getAll() {
        
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(bookservice.getAll());
                return json;
            }
        
        }
    
    
    #SpringBoot service file -
    




 @Service
        public class BookService {
            
            @Autowired
            BookRepo repo;
        
            public void addBook(Book book) {
                repo.save(book);
                repo.flush();
            }
            public List<Book> getAll(){
                return repo.findAll();
            }
            public void deleteBook(int id) {
                
                repo.delete(Book.builder().id(id).build());
            }
            
            
        }
    
    #Angular service.ts-
    




import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class BookService {
    
      constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }
    
    getAll(){
      return this.http.get<any>("http://localhost:8080/getBooks");
    }
    addBook(user:any){
      return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/addBook?id="+ user.id + "&name=" +user.name + "&author="+user.author);
    }
    deleteBook(id:any){
      return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/deleteBook?id="+id);
    }
    }
    
    #appComponent.ts -
```

books:any;

```
  constructor(private service:BookService) {}

  ngOnInit():void{
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData():void {
    this.service.getAll().subscribe(response => {
      this.books = response;
      console.log(this.books);
    })
  }

#appComponent.html -



<p *ngFor="let temp in books">
    {{temp.name}} -- {{temp.author}}
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here instead of using `*ngFor="let temp in books"`, we should have `*ngFor="let temp of books"`. Please use the below snippet:

```
<p *ngFor="let temp of books">
    {{temp.name}} -- {{temp.author}}
</p>
```

This could resolve your issue if we are getting the data correctly in `this.books` property. Hope this helps.

Comment: Still not working problem not resolved

Answer (score 0):

- Use the Observable error block to see if you are getting any errors from
  the API or check the response format.
- Your API returns a String value to the front end either you need to remove the API to return List<> or use JSON.parse(this.books) to convert the response to Array.
- Use "of" instead "in" inside *ngFor.
- Check the availability of "CommonModule" in the module that your component declared.

  ```
  @GetMapping("/getBooks")
  public List<Books> getAll() {

      return bookservice.getAll();
  }

  constructor(private service:BookService) {}

   ngOnInit():void{
     this.loadData();
   }

   loadData():void {
     this.service.getAll().subscribe(response => {
       this.books = response;
       console.log(this.books);
     },error=>{
       console.log(error)
     })
   }

  #appComponent.html -


  <p *ngFor="let temp of books">
      {{temp.name}} -- {{temp.author}}
  </p>
  ```